# Reindex sublevel of pandas dataframe multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a time series dataframe and I would like to reindex it by Trials and Measurements.

Simplified, I have this:

```
                value
Trial         
    1     0        13
          1         3
          2         4
    2     3       NaN
          4        12
    3     5        34
```

Which I want to turn into this:

```
                  value
Trial    
    1      0        13
           1         3
           2         4
    2      0       NaN
           1        12
    3      0        34
```

How can I best do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just yesterday, the illustrious Andy Hayden added this feature to version 0.13 of pandas, which will be released any day now. See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#enumerate-group-items) for usage example he added to the docs.

If you are comfortable installing the development version of pandas from source, you can use it now.

```
df['Measurements'] = df.reset_index().groupby('Trial').cumcount()
```

The following code is equivalent, if less pithy, and will work on any recent version of pandas.

```
grouped = df.reset_index().groupby('Trial')
df['Measurements'] = grouped.apply(lambda x: Series(np.arange(len(x)), x.index))
```

Finally, `df.set_index(['Trial', 'Measurements'], inplace=True)` to get your desired result.

Comment: haha! "illustrious" +1 ;) (Note: cumcount also works with dupes in index, but "equivalent" doesn't... I was a bit cheeky in the docs and said "*essentially* equivalent" :p)

Comment: what if My index isn't called ('measurements') - but rather has no name at all?

Comment: Unnamed index levels can be specified using the ``level`` keyword, like ``groupby(level=1)``.

Comment: and how do I select the first subindex of the first index? df.ix[1,0] selects a column :-/

Comment: also, each trial has ~242 measurements in my dataframe - for some reason the code you pasted above gives me measurement indices from 242 to 484 :/

Comment: [Read](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index).

Comment: yes, this isn't working `df.ix['bar', 'two']`. Or wasn't actually, apparently your code would not work if ['Trial'] was already set as an indey when it was run. Strangely enough, after I run you code, df['Trial'] no longer works :( which is a pity because I wanted to do this in order to better apply the same function to multiple trials (I want to downsample all of the measurements in every trial to two - just two).