# Reindex 2nd level in incomplete multi-level dataframe to be complete, inserting NANs on missing rows

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I need to reindex the 2nd level of a pandas dataframe, so that the 2nd level becomes a (complete) list `0,...,(N-1)` for each 1st level index.

- I tried using [Allan/Hayden's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104874/reindex-sublevel-of-pandas-dataframe-multiindex), but unfortunately it only creates an index with as many rows as previously existing.
- What I want is that **for each new index, new rows are inserted (with nan values).**

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'first': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'three'], 
  'second': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1],
  'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
})
print df

   first  second  value
0    one       0      1
1    one       1      2
2    one       2      3
3    two       0      4
4    two       1      5
5  three       1      6

# Tried using Allan/Hayden's approach, but no good for this, doesn't add the missing rows    
df['second'] = df.reset_index().groupby(['first']).cumcount()
print df
   first  second  value
0    one       0      1
1    one       1      2
2    one       2      3
3    two       0      4
4    two       1      5
5  three       0      6
```

My desired result is:

```
   first  second  value
0    one       0      1
1    one       1      2
2    one       2      3
3    two       0      4
4    two       1      5
4    two       2      nan <-- INSERTED
5  three       0      6
5  three       1      nan <-- INSERTED
5  three       2      nan <-- INSERTED
```

Comment: Could you just first create the data frame with all of the rows you need. Then update it with the values you have.

Comment: are the indices in "second" always contiguous and starting from `0`?

Comment: Missing words from title: you want to *Reindex 2nd level in **incomplete** multi-level dataframe **to be complete, insert NANs on missing rows***

Comment: Also, saying `np.arange(N)` is pretty obscure to non-numpy users, clearer to just say `0,...,(N-1)`

Comment: In general, don't use `groupby()` as a poor-man's multiindex, do `.set_index(['first', 'second'])` wherever possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can first set columns `first` and `second` as multi-level index, and then `reindex`.

```
# your data
# ==========================
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'first': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'three'], 
  'second': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1],
  'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
})

df

   first  second  value
0    one       0      1
1    one       1      2
2    one       2      3
3    two       0      4
4    two       1      5
5  three       1      6

# processing
# ============================
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['first'].unique(), np.arange(3)], names=['first', 'second'])

df.set_index(['first', 'second']).reindex(multi_index).reset_index()

   first  second  value
0    one       0      1
1    one       1      2
2    one       2      3
3    two       0      4
4    two       1      5
5    two       2    NaN
6  three       0    NaN
7  three       1      6
8  three       2    NaN
```

Comment: why is the `.reset_index` required after `.reindex`?